# Exporting from Adobe CS to a format the client can easily update?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, newsletter

I have a client for whom I've designed a newsletter. I did this in Photoshop, since it's the program I'm the must accustomized to (I know InDesign would've been the "right" choice). And now I need to hand over a file that can be used by my client as a template for writing these newsletters. How do I do this in a way so that anyone with just basic computer knowledge can make them? In Microsoft Word/OpenOffice for example. The file is a bit image-heavy so it needs to be versatile.

Comment: As Marc says, how they'll use it is critical: email, desktop print, external printing?

Comment: PHotoshop is completely the wrong tool for a newsletter.

Comment: I won't put this in as an answer, but you should be aware that the client probably does not have the capability required to create a good looking newsletter, especially an image heavy one, from any template you provide. My personal experience is that people "want a button" and their unfamiliarity with the process makes them think that what they asked for is possible. It is not, unless you write a program that can intelligently adjust the content. This sounds cynical, but they wouldn't need you if they could do this themselves.

Comment: It's going to be used mainly for print. But we might need an e-mail version later on.

Comment: I already know Photoshop is not the correct tool to use. No, they are not capable of creates the newsletter themselves. But they don't need to be. What I'm trying to create is basically a document where the header, bckground and footer stays te same, but they edit and change the content. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they require a template, then the best option is probably to build the template in the application itself, using other apps like Photoshop to create assets like logos you'll reuse.

What's the newsletter for? If it's to be emailed, then you're probably better off creating a MailChimp or Campaign Monitor template. Emailing Word documents often isn't a good solution.

Comment: It's to be printed and mailed. You are right, I just assumed there would be an easier way to export from Adobe CS to a format that is easier to edit for the not-so-tech-savvy.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Marc Edwards response, if you're going to email this out to its intended recipients you should probably create an HTML template. MailChimp allows you to upload html pages with images as a .zip file.

If it's a print template you should probably be considering using something else - Photoshop is a fine piece of software but it's usually the wrong tool for tasks such as document layout (I've seen some fantastic posters done in Photoshop but they were almost more of a full-page image). If you're going to be doing this kind of thing you may want to become more familiar with some of the other pieces of software in the CS. It may be that you end up using Illustrator (great for vector art or single-page layouts) or InDesign (definitely a page layout solution) and sending a .pdf off to your client.